# Ni No Kuni Errand 78

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

So I need Kaleidostones and Scrolls of Truth.
Online the best recommendation seems to be grinding in Glittering Grotto and trying to random encounter Golden Dragamuffins and Golden Bedraggles then defending till you get a gold glim for Swaine.
This is a *lot* of grinding. Does the wisdom of stack exchange have anything they can offer in addition to minimize my grinding time?

Comment: Pretty sure I just using his standard Mugshot and hoped for the best. I think I was done in less than an hour. Saying that, I remember I did something which involved grinding gold glims so maybe it was this. Either way, less then an hour isn't much considering how much time I had already invested into the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this took me about 3 hours in total so I'll leave the question open in case anyone else has a quicker answer.

In Glittering Grotto go to the last waystone, there are two ways to get there, the straight path or through a hidden tunnel. On both approaches there are groups of three enimies. These six enimies are the ones you want to fight to get Kaleidostones.

On Tombstone Trail go to the middle way waypoint and continue into the cave. At the split in the cave there is an enemy and the only enemey to your left and the first enemy to your right. These are the 3 enemies you want to fight to get Schrolls of Truth.

My most successful gameplan was:

- Use Marcassin, Oliver, and Swaine
- Equip Marcassin with the weakest wand in your possession
- Set everyone to do nothing in tactics
- Fight the enemies listed above even if their world avatar isn't the gold encounter
- If you don't get the ecounter with a gold, kill everything with Oliver's Astra spell
- If you do get the encounter with a gold, use Marcassin's pulse to kill other enemies and then the gold encounter. Hopefully in the course of this one of the enemies will drop a gold glim. Switch to swaine take the glim and use his light fingers on the gold encounter
- If you don't get a gold glim at least try Swaine's mugshot on the gold encounter before you kill him